# common timings between Time intervals Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to get the common timings between two time intervals. Is there any way to do this

For Example, Timings for Interval1 is 6:00 AM-11:00 PM, Interval2 is  7:00 AM-9:00 AM here the common timing is from 7:00 AM-9:00 AM .How can i get this through Objective C.Is there any way   to compare timings please help me...

Comment: you mean the overlapping time of two strings. please edit title and question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two strings which first you have to make into dates:

```
    //setup a formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"]; 
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

    //convert 1. range
    NSString *dateRange1 = @"6:00 AM - 11:00 AM"; 
    NSArray *dateRangeComps1 = [dateRange1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
    NSDate *startDate1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateRangeComps1[0]];
    NSDate *endDate1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateRangeComps1[1]];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", startDate1, endDate1);

    //convert 2. range
    NSString *dateRange2 = @"7:00 AM - 9:00 AM"; 
    NSArray *dateRangeComps2 = [dateRange2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
    NSDate *startDate2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateRangeComps2[0]];
    NSDate *endDate2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateRangeComps2[1]];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", startDate2, endDate2);
```

Then you calculate the overlap

```
    //overlapping date range        
    NSDate *latestStartDate = [startDate1 laterDate:startDate2];
    NSDate *earliestEndDate = [endDate1 earlierDate:endDate2];
    if([latestStartDate timeIntervalSinceDate:earliestEndDate] <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", latestStartDate, earliestEndDate);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No Overlap");
    }
```

Comment: Thnx for ur answer got it

Answer (score 2):

Create a class which describes start and finish dates of the interval.

.h file:

```
@interface Interval

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSDate *finishDate;

- (id)initWithStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate finishDate:(NSDate *)finishDate;

- (NSTimeInterval)timeInterval;

- (Interval *)commonIntervalWith:(Interval *)interval;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation

- (id)initWithStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate finishDate:(NSDate *)finishDate
{
    _startDate = startDate;
    _finishDate = finishDate;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)timeInterval
{
    // If startDate or finishDate is nil then return 0,
    // otherwise return interval between dates

    return _startDate ? [_finishDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate] : 0;
}

- (Interval *)commonIntervalWith:(Interval *)interval
{
    NSDate *lastStartDate = [_startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:interval.startDate] > 0 ? _startDate : interval.startDate;

    NSDate *earliestFinishDate = [_finishDate timeIntervalSinceDate:interval.finishDate] > 0 ? interval.finishDate : _finishDate;

    if([lastStartDate timeIntervalSinceDate:earliestFinishDate] > 0)
    {
        return [[Interval alloc] initWithStartDate:nil finishDate:nil];
    }

    return [[Interval alloc] initWithStartDate:lastStartDate finishDate:earliestFinishDate];
}

@end
```

Usage example:

```
NSDate *date1 = ...; //Interval1 start date
NSDate *date2 = ...; //Interval1 finish date
NSDate *date3 = ...; //Interval2 start date
NSDate *date4 = ...; //Interval2 finish date

Interval *interval1 = [[Interval alloc] initWithStartDate:date1 finishDate:date2];
Interval *interval2 = [[Interval alloc] initWithStartDate:date3 finishDate:date4];
Interval *commonInterval = [interval1 commonIntervalWith:interval2];
NSTimeInterval commonTimeInterval = [commonInterval timeInterval];
```

To convert string representation of date to NSDate use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: A direct solution (instead of wrapping everything into a custom class) might be easier to understand for a beginner, but that is only my opinion. - Note that you can simplify the calculations slightly by using the ealierDate: and laterDate: methods.

Answer (score -1):

You could build `NSDate` objects from the timings, and compare them via `NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSinceDate:`. See the [NSDate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a).

```
NSDate* date1 = /*however you got the date */;
NSDate* date2 = /*however you got the date */;
NSTimeInterval difference = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
```

If your dates are strings, you could convert them to `NSDate`s via an `NSDateFormatter`. The see [NSDateFormatter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: this is time difference not time intersection

Comment: Thnx for the quick reply,Using timeIntervalSinceDate i can get only difference between two timings ,but what i need is common time in two intervals like 7:00 Pm, 8:00 Pm ...